# Swift AppleMap MKOverlayRenderer Image Zoom In Bug

Tags: swift, rotation, mkoverlay, apple-maps

Hi I need Help I do control Apple Map

I want overlay image on map

I use MKOverlayRenderer and this function
override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext)

and then success overlay

but map zoom level 2.0 over than image broken

if not use CGContext.rotate then image are not broken
but use rotate then image are broken

```
class IndoorInfoOverlay: NSObject, MKOverlay {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let boundingMapRect: MKMapRect

    init(indoorInfo: IndoorInfo) {
      boundingMapRect = indoorInfo.overlayBoundingMapRect
      coordinate = indoorInfo.midCoordinate
    }
}

class IndoorInfoOverlayView: MKOverlayRenderer {
  var overlayImage: UIImage
  var parent: IndoorMapView

  init(overlay: MKOverlay, overlayImage: UIImage,_ parent: IndoorMapView) {
      self.overlayImage = overlayImage
      self.parent = parent
      super.init(overlay: overlay)
  }

  override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
    guard let imageReference = overlayImage.cgImage else { return }
      let bearing = degreesToRadians(360 - (Double(self.parent.floorData!.FLOOR_BEARING) ?? 0))

      let rect = self.rect(for: overlay.boundingMapRect)
      context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
      context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -rect.size.height)
      if self.parent.floorData != nil {
          context.rotate(by: bearing)
      }
      context.draw(imageReference, in: rect, byTiling: false)
  }
                               
  private func degreesToRadians(_ x:Double) -> Double {
    return (Double.pi * x / 180.0)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is likely because the `MKOverlayRenderer` class uses a tiling mechanism to display the image, and the image isn't being properly tiled at higher zoom levels.

One solution to this problem would be to use a larger image that can be properly tiled at higher zoom levels. Another option would be to use a different mechanism for displaying the image on the map, such as using a `MKAnnotationView` with a custom image.

Comment: Thanks answer, I try indoor location service so i need MKOverlayRenderer, i did image resize 2X but same broken image this image are like cutting